# Creating Dynamic ComboBox in C#

Tags: c#, combobox

I'm new to Visual Studio 2010 C# and I'm creating an application where the user will select the number of textboxes will be shown in a form.  For example, if the user will select "2" automatically there will be 2 boxes will be shown in the form.

This is the screenshots that I want to create.

[image: Select number of textboxes to be shown]

[image: The output when the user select 2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess what you need to know is dynamic creation of controls.
To do what you want here you need to:

- Create a control
- Add control to form
- Set control location, size and anything else you need

It would go something like this:

```
Texbox texbox = new Textbox();
Controls.Add(textbox);
textbox.Top = 20;
textbox.Left = 200;
textbox.Width = 200;
textbox.Name = "textbox1";
```

So that there's something left for you to do, you should repeat steps above in a loop, and calculate location of each textbox so that they're not stacked up.

Comment: thank you!. it really did help me. by the way, can I set the location and sizes of the textboxes?

Comment: yes, sure. location is set in example above by changing Top and Left properties (sorry to perplex you, I know there is also Location property). Size is changed with Width and Height properties, but for TextBox Height doesn't make much sense unless you change it to be multiline textbox or change font.

Comment: Can I set a textbox name for the textbox created after selecting in combobox? So that the values of it will be stored in the database.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do, but yes, you can set TextBox Name property at any time. If you need to store any additional data, you also have Tag property on any type of control.

Answer (score 1):

```
comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i = 0;  
    int y = 0;
    while (i < int.Parse(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()))
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.TextBox tt = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        y = y + 30;
        tt.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, y);
        this.Controls.Add(tt);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps